# In any web site, the image always downloaded in the background, right?

Tags: background, web, image-loading

Just to confirm, the image always downloaded in another thread which is different with the page text loading thread??

I put  in my page, refer to a image on internet, the all text always show up firstly.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `html` file contains all the prose and refers to pictures, so in whatever threads you do that you first download the text. Whether it's rendered before pictures are downloaded is up to UA and they may or may not be the same in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Browser and the website. In most cases the Browser loads the "main html" where there are references to the Pics and other things.
If the Website loads most of the text-content via AJAX it could be kind of the other way round.

.. but in most cases you are right